# The program should loop back to data entry upon confirmation by the user and will terminate as confirmed by the user

Tags: java

I would like to loop my code to go back to the input the numerator and denominator part by asking for y/n input. I am using an encapsulation ( school project) and I am not sure how to do it. Here is the instructions:

Write a Java program with the following specifications:

1. Define 2 private attributes in Fraction class, the numerator and the denominator.  Define the constructor for this class.
2. Define the setters (mutators) and the getters (accessors) for the Fraction class.
3. Define also the following custom methods in the Fraction class:
   a.  showFractionForm
   b.  determineLowestTerm
   c.  determineDecimalEquivalent
   d.  determineFractionType
4. The fraction types are as follows: 
   a.  Proper Fraction – numerator is less than the denominator
   b.  Improper Fraction – numerator is greater than the denominator, but the quotient is a real number (ex: 3.45)
   c.  Whole Number – numerator is greater than the denominator, but the quotient has no decimal part
5. Create a main class named Math.  This class should contain the main method.
6. Instantiate an object of the Fraction class in the main method.
7. Invoke the methods of the Fraction class in the main method to display the requirements as shown in the sample output:

This is the sample output:

[image: Program output]

[image]

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main 
{

    public static void main (String[]args) 
    {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    Fraction frac = new Fraction ();

    System.out.println ("Enter numerator: ");
        frac.setNum (input.nextInt ());
    System.out.println ("Enter denominator: ");
        frac.setDen (input.nextInt ());

    System.out.println ("***************OUTPUT***************");
    System.out.println ("NUMERATOR: " + frac.getNum ());
    System.out.println ("DENOMINATOR: " + frac.getDen ());
    System.out.println ("FRACTION FORM: " + frac.getShowFractionForm ());
    System.out.println ("LOWEST TERM: " + frac.getDetermineLowestTerm ());
    System.out.println ("LOWEST TERM: " + frac.getDetermineFractionType());
    System.out.println ("DECIMAL EQUIVALENT: " + frac.getDetermineDecimalEquivalent ());

} 

public static class Fraction 
{

private int num, den;
private String showFractionForm;
private String determineFractionType;
private String determineLowestTerm;
private double determineDecimalEquivalent;


//accessors


public String getShowFractionForm () 
{

String num1 = Integer.toString (num);
String den1 = Integer.toString (den);
showFractionForm = num + "/" + den;
return showFractionForm;
}

public String getDetermineFractionType()
{
if (num % den == 0) {
    determineFractionType = ("WHOLE NUMBER");
} else if (num < den ) {
    determineFractionType = ("PROPER FRACTION");
} else if (num > den) {
    determineFractionType = ("IMPROPER FRACTION");
}
return determineFractionType;
}

public String getDetermineLowestTerm () 
{
int smaller = num < den ? num : den;
int HCF = -1;
    for (int i = smaller; i > 0; --i){
        if (num % i == 0 && den % i == 0)
    {
HCF = i;
determineLowestTerm = (num / HCF) + "/" + (den / HCF);
break;
    }
}
return determineLowestTerm;
}

public double getDetermineDecimalEquivalent () 
{
determineDecimalEquivalent = (double) num / den;
return determineDecimalEquivalent;
}

public int getNum ()
{
return num;
}

public int getDen ()
{
return den;
}


//mutators

public void ShowFractionForm (String form) 
{
this.showFractionForm = form;
} 
public void setDetermineFractionType(String type)
{
    this.determineFractionType = type;
}
public void setDetermineLowestTerm (String term) 
{
this.determineLowestTerm = term;
} 

public void setDetermineDecimalEquivalent (int decimal) 
{
this.determineDecimalEquivalent = decimal;
} 

public void setNum (int num)
{
this.num = num;
} 

public void setDen (int den)
{
this.den = den;
} 

} 

}
```

Comment: TL;DR .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can try smth like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Fraction frac = new Fraction();
    boolean isContinue = true;
    while (isContinue) {
        System.out.println("Enter numerator: ");
        frac.setNum(input.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter denominator: ");
        frac.setDen(input.nextInt());

        System.out.println("***************OUTPUT***************");
        System.out.println("NUMERATOR: " + frac.getNum());
        System.out.println("DENOMINATOR: " + frac.getDen());
        System.out.println("FRACTION FORM: " + frac.getShowFractionForm());
        System.out.println("LOWEST TERM: " + frac.getDetermineLowestTerm());
        System.out.println("LOWEST TERM: " + frac.getDetermineFractionType());
        System.out.println("DECIMAL EQUIVALENT: " + frac.getDetermineDecimalEquivalent());
        System.out.println("Input again? [y/n]");
        String result = input.next();
        isContinue = result.equals("y");
    }
}
```

more about while loop: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_while_loop.asp

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this would help you:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
    System.out.println("Again? y/n");
    String answer = sc.next(); 

    while (answer.equals("y")) {
        System.out.println("Looping job!");         

        System.out.println("Again? y/n");
        answer = sc.next(); 
        if(answer.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("bye T.T");
            break;
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Hello, can you show me where to add that in my main function?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap everything starting from:

```
System.out.println ("Enter numerator: ");
```

in a while loop. Like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter numerator: ");
        //enumerator code here
        System.out.println("Enter denominator: ");
        //denominator code here

        //some additional code here

        System.out.println("Again? ");
        if (input.nextLine().toLowerCase().equals("n")) break;
    }

}
```